# Calling a method inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to trigger a method from inside the model where it is defined. But I am getting an "undefined method `completed_mission_names'" when I try to start my server. Can anybody help me find what I'm doing wrong ?

```
class MenteeProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Update trackable attributes with succeeded missions
  MenteeProfile.completed_mission_names

protected

  def last_completed_mission_action
  end

  def self.completed_mission_names
  end
end
```

Comment: if yr inside model just call as u see `self.completed_mission_names`, if yr in controller or view then `MenteeProfile.completed_mission_names`

Comment: Move the invocation to the bottom of the class definition. Or even better, outside. Right after the class definition will be fine. Calling the method in a Rails initializer file (`config/initializers/whatever.rb`) would be even better (assuming you want to perform a one-time initialization).

Comment: Following Tim mee answer and thread shared, I have put the method I wanted to call inside the Class, works much better. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified to the max, you are trying to do this:

```
class A
  A.foo
  def self.foo
    puts 'Calling foo!'
  end
end
```

This does not work because the method `foo` is not defined when you try to invoke it. You must define it first, then you can call it. Like so:

```
class B
  def self.foo
    puts 'Calling foo!'
  end
  B.foo
end
```

You could also call just `foo` instead of `B.foo` from within the class definition. You can add the protected keyword anywhere you like, it will not have any impact on class methods whatsoever.